# Select objects based on grandchild attribute with joins in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Suppose I have the following Models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bars
has_many :bazs, :through => :bars

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :foo
has_many :bazs

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :bar
```

Suppose Baz has a "name" attribute. What is the best way for me to select all Foo where Baz has the name "x"?

I had thought I could do something like `Foo.join(:baz).where('bazs.name' => 'x')` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be work!

```
Foo.joins(:bazs).where(bazs: {name: 'x'})
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried this several times and it was not working. Tried it again with Success. Thanks! Also for the sake of anyone else finding this... Avoid dupicates by tacking on .group('foos.id')

Comment: @Patm avoid duplicates with an `includes` instead of `joins`

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes, you are correct. I checked out both methods and using joins with group is actually significantly faster than includes... at least with my large sample data set.

Answer (score 2):

You can includes the relations as they declared:

```
Foo.includes(bars: :bazs)
```

And then you can apply your condition on the included table(s):

```
Foo.includes(bars: :bazs).where(bars: { title: 'Hey'}, bazs: { id: nil })
```

---

Since you already declared the :bazs in the Foo model via a "has_many-through" relation, you can do:

```
Foo.includes(:bazs).where(bazs: { id: 12 })
```

Comment: thank you - but how would the first response change if there were great grandchildren involved and you wanted to navigate through another table?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon If you are talking about a self-referential relation, with any depth (like Category has_many :child_categories and each child_categories can also have child, and so on), then I strongly advise to use a SQL `VIEW` with recursive to simulate the ancestors/descendants relation. It will save you a lot of performances.

Comment: No, this is something too complex for Rails and involve some knowledge of SQL. You can easily find examples of recursive views for parent/child relationships on Google.